california taxes on non california sources of income when husband and wife are residing in different states
Assume husband is moving out of the California permanently (with out stepping back in) and lives in non-community property state (Oregon, Wyoming).
California wife doesn't have any income from either California or other sources.
If filing MFJ at federal level, and MFJ at state, does the joint filers has to pay the taxes for the  income earned in Orgeon ?
How about MFJ at federal and MFS at state (because the husband doesn't have California sourced income and has lived out of California whole year) , does the California spouse have to pay taxes on the Oregon spouse's income.
I know if Oregon were a community property state, then you'll have to split the Oregon income in 1/2 and  pay California taxes on one half while filing MFJ for california.


If filing MFJ at federal level, and MFJ at state, does the joint filers has to pay the taxes for the income earned in Orgeon ?

Well obviously they need to pay federal and Oregon taxes on the income earned in Oregon. If you are asking about California taxes, then no, because there is no California income, and the California resident does not have any income. The person earning the income is domiciled in Oregon, a non-community-property state, so all of that income is solely that person's income, and it is not half the other spouse's income. Therefore, the California spouse has no income.
Now if it were the other way around (California spouse has income and Oregon spouse doesn't), then the California spouse's income would be half each spouse's income, so all of the income would be taxed in California but half also taxed in Oregon, and they can take a credit for that half on the California return.

How about MFJ at federal and MFS at state (because the husband doesn't have California sourced income and has lived out of California whole year) , does the California spouse have to pay taxes on the Oregon spouse's income.

No, for the same reason as above. (No California income and the California resident has no income.) You can see this from Publication 1031, section "How To Split Income on Form 540NR" (page 13), in cases 3 and 4, for where one spouse is domiciled in a community property state (e.g. California) and one is domiciled in a separate property state (e.g. Oregon). When filing separately, the community property state spouse would put in column E (California amounts) half of their income taxable by California (which in your case is 0 since the California spouse has no income), and the separate property state spouse would put in column E all of their income taxable by California (which in your case is 0 since it's all Oregon income of an Oregon resident) plus half of the other spouse's income taxable by California (which is again 0 because the California spouse has no income).
Again, if it were the other way around (California spouse has income and Oregon spouse doesn't), then the California spouse's income would be half each spouse's income, so all of the income would be taxed in California but half also taxed in Oregon, and they can take a credit for that half on the California return.

I agree with you. however I heard cases where CA FTB looks at intent of non-california spouse to move back.

The person earning the income is domiciled in Oregon, a non-community-property state, so all of that income is solely that person's income, and it is not half the other spouse's income. Therefore, the California spouse has no income - no, that's not how communities work. You can't deprive your spouse of property and income just by moving away. The Oregon income is quasi-community. You're confusing tax sourcing rules with family law attribution rules.

@cyborgt8 that's a question re determination of residency. CA FTB is in fact quite aggressive in asserting residency and having spouse remaining in the state is a strong signal of your intent to return and as such remaining resident. But it didn't sound like that's what you're asking about, both my and this answer assumed you're asking about community property split.

If you read the comments here, I recommend you to read my comments under littleadv's answer. I believe littleadv's comments here are based on an incorrect understanding of the law. Specifically, quasi-community property is a concept that only take effects only when both spouses are domiciled in CA at the time they divorce or die. They may have moved out of CA before they divorce or die. Hence, quasi-community property rules don't change who owns the property.


If filing MFJ at federal level, and MFJ at state, does the joint filers has to pay the taxes for the income earned in Orgeon ?

Yes.

How about MFJ at federal and MFS at state (because the husband doesn't have California sourced income and has lived out of California whole year) , does the California spouse have to pay taxes on the Oregon spouse's income.

This is a more interesting case, and may require a professional assistance (a lawyer probably). Basically, you're asking whether the community property rules of California marriage apply to income outside of California. They do, generally, and my understanding is that even if the husband is in Oregon, California family law applies due to wife's California residency. But as I said - you'd probably need a professional opinion.

California family law do you have any reference like FTB pub? I'd think it should not because Publication 1031, section "How To Split Income on Form 540NR" (page 13) would not serve any purpose.

@cyborgt8 right... read it carefully. FTB is not in the business of enforcing family laws, only tax laws. But what the rules on that page say (especially case #4, relevant to your situation) is that the income is still split between the spouses.

I'm not sure if I can agree with the second answer. The husband residents and is domiciled in Oregon, so Oregon family law applies to the husband's earned income in Oregon. Since Oregon is a common law state, the husband owns all those income. This is the end of analysis. California law doesn't apply in this regard.

@xuhdev Please familiarize yourself with this. California law doesn't apply in this regard - that's not up to you to decide.

@littleadv quasi-community property is a different concept. Quasi-community properties, as defined by California law, are only treated like community properties upon divorce or death only if at that time the person is domiciled in CA. It's well possible that the spouses are both out of CA at that time. For tax purposes, likely the present interest is also not treated as community property either.

@xuhdev my experience with family law in California is very different. But then again, as opposed to armchair lawyers here, I suggested the OP seeks a professional guidance.

@littleadv If the OP is asking for their own situation, they should consult an attorney, not asking here.
I don't know why your experience is different, here's a reference: In re Marriage of Roesch, 83 Cal.App.3d 96, 147 Cal. Rptr. 586 (Cal. Ct. App. 1978). Section IV(5). Short version, in the case, the married couple divorced, with one domiciled in CA and one in PA. The court ruled that quasi-community property statutes didn't apply, because CA didn't have a substantial interest in the properties owned by the PA person.

@xuhdev married and separated in PA, why would it.... I think the OP should consult an attorney with the specifics of their case. We don't know where they were married, what pre/post nups might there be, what's the context, etc. there's also the question of residency for the Oregon spouse which also non trivial

@littleadv Please read the reference. This is not about the location of the marriage. This is about their domiciles upon divorce and the source of the properties. it seems unconstitutional to me that a state applies its family law to properties that doesn't have substantial nexus to the state and whose owner is domiciled out of the state. This also reconciles with the court's reasoning. While I agree the OP should seek for an attorney if this is their own situation, this discussion really focuses on your answer.

@xuhdev in that case the marriage started, continued, and ended while both parties lived in PA. The CA court was involved because the husband initiated the divorce after moving to CA - which was the separation. Quote: "When husband left the household he established his residence in California". The CA court ruled that as such CA community property rules never applied. That's not the case the OP described. In fact, the OP is describing the exact opposite.

You only quoted one fact statement. There are many facts in a case. These facts together build the whole circumstances and none of which determines the outcome of the case. Hence, judges tend to write out facts as long as they support their opinion in some way. The core principles in the case are clear: CA can't reach its arm to the PA properties owned by the PA-domiciled person due to the lack of substantial nexus. It is unimaginable that CA law can constitutionally declare half of some property belonging to someone else when neither the property nor the owner has substantial nexus to CA.

@xuhdev belonging to someone else when neither the property nor the owner has substantial nexus to CA - but that's exactly the point of contention. Can a spouse shield income that would otherwise be community by fleeing the state and working remotely? Does the spouse whose spouse lives in CA really lacks nexus by just stepping out for a second? Your whole argument hinges on the geographic location, but the CA FTB is quite notorious for not allowing such an easy way out.

@littleadv FTB has been notorious for not allowing such to carry out by arguing that the person who leaves CA has not given up their CA domicile, such as they intend to come back to CA. The OP's question has made it clear that the husband is domiciled in OR. You are confusing domicile determination with how differently domiciled persons are treated under CA family law. Merely leaving CA physically doesn't make one disconnected to CA. How substantially one is connected to the state is based on the whole circumstances.

Now I kind of see where you experience comes from. Your understanding is: "Husband who leaves CA while wife still stays in CA is still subject to CA taxation." This is true in many cases, when the husband fails to establish that he has lost CA domicile. This is likely true if the husband leaves CA only to dodge some taxes, such as substantial capital gain. Maybe you have some clients having this in mind. But if the husband has truly left CA permanently and established domicile elsewhere, CA would lose a lot of power over the husband, and can't tax his earning in OR after his leaving.

@xuhdev so you see it's not as clear cut as you initially presented....

Did you read my comments? For the OP's question, it's clear. I was trying to guess  why you have misunderstood the law due to your "experience with CA family law".

if CA-FTB believes that Husband has left the state to avoid the taxes and due to his connection to spouse is still domiciled in CA  (even after getting OR residence, DL,register to vote), then CA-FTB can just wait and see if the husband later returns back to CA. and they can make a claim (example: husband leaves and returns back in a year or two, but if he is away for more than few (5,10) years, then they cannot make such claim)

@cyborgt8 yeah, that's not how this works. The burden of proof is on the Oregon spouse, not the FTB.

the burden of proof is on the prosecutor  not on the defendant.

@cyborgt8 it's not a criminal case. If the FTB determines that you have not ceased being resident - you will need to prove them wrong.

if the husband is living , voting, DL in oregon and doesn't visit california, then he is resident of oregon. I think you meant "domicile" instead of "resident". the definition for domicile is vague and FTB can be overreaching here.
